# Hugo utility changes HGST drive firmware through USB3?

Tags: advanced-format

I got a WD Elements external drive. And from the looks of it it seems to have a HGST helium filled 8TB drive inside (SMART says it has the code 022). It is possible to change the firmware of this NASdrive to make it a native 4k reporting drive to the OS. WDreds do not support the 512e > 4kn change. Anyway. Who has experience with this Hugo utility and can comment if I could safely change the firmware through USB 3.1?

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/please-help-convert-hgst-he10-and-he12-to-4kn.27668/post-290933

I have good news and I have bad news.

The good news is, someone in that thread says they were able to successfully convert shucked 8TB EZAZ drives from 512e to 4Kn. The bad news is the very next comment is someone who bricked their 10TB EMAZ drives by trying to do the same thing, which somehow ATA Security Locked the drives.

I have a pair of 10TB EMAZ drives behind a hardware RAID controller that I would **love** to throw in RAID10 with two HGST drives, but I don't want to risk it with the stupid drives now being worth twice what I paid for them. One of the HGST drives is 512e, but it's a SAS drive and I think I can just do it with sgutil if I put the drive in a 2nd machine that has a plain HBA, and I know it will work with WD's "HUGO" tool behind an HBA as well.

Either way, you won't be doing it over USB with that JMicron bridge chip in the way, you'll have to shuck it first.